# Why does std::vector call the destructor while leaving a different scope?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some code like this

```
std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> RoverPlanner::get_paths(const char *filename) const
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    doc.load_file(filename);
    pugi::xml_node root = doc.document_element();

    std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> paths;
    for (auto path_node : root.children()) {
        std::vector<cuarl_path::Segment*> segments;
        for (auto segment_node : path_node.children())
        {
            //do stuff to populate the `segments` vector
        }

        cuarl_path::Path* path = new cuarl_path::Path(segments);
        paths.push_back(*path); //Path destructor called here
    }

    return paths;
}
```

Here's the call stack
[image]

The issue seems that the std::vector "paths" calls its destructor, but I don't understand why. The scope has not ended.

Comment: There's also a memory leak at that point.

Comment: @FredLarson Could you explain why?

Comment: It doesn't destruct the vector, it destructs the `cuarl_path::Path`.

Comment: There's a `new`, but where's the `delete`?

Comment: `cuarl_path::Path* path = new cuarl_path::Path(segments);
        paths.push_back(*path);` can just be `paths.push_back(cuarl_path::Path(segments));`

Comment: @tkausl is this because of the deferencing? Why is the path getting destroyed?

Comment: @FredLarson Well I would delete the path when the program shuts down

Comment: @NathanOliver Or `paths.emplace_back(segments);`

Comment: How would you delete it? You no longer have a pointer to that memory.

Comment: @FredLarson Now I see, I definitely lose track of that pointer

Comment: It's re-allocating the vector, because you didn't call `std::vector<T>::reserve()`. If you know exactly how many elements you are going to need, you should always do that. Otherwise it's performing move+destruct for each element already stored, once it realizes the vector was too small. `paths.reserve(root.children.size());` just before entering the loop.

Comment: Ok thanks, I brought your change @NathanOliver

Comment: @Ext3h Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work, assuming I did it correctly. I first implemented NathanOliver's changes. Then, I did this

`std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> paths;`
 
`int path_count = std::distance(root.children().begin(), root.children().end());`

`paths.reserve(path_count);`

Comment: @CedricMartens NathanOliver's change (still using `push_back()`) results in temporary objects, which are also having their destructor called. Using `emplace_back()` together with `reserve()` avoids temporary objects entirely.

Comment: @Ext3h I simply replaced the `paths.push_back()` to `paths.emplace_back()`, unfortunately, it does not seem like it resolves the issue. It is still calling the paths destructor https://imgur.com/a/ltJI7Rf and the call stack. It seems to me that perhaps the path that im passing as an argument is destroyed immediately as it falls out of scope. Is this possible? Please check : https://imgur.com/a/SqFd5Ri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
paths.push_back(*path);
```

this does a few things.

1. It constructs a `Path` copy from the heap-allocated `*path` object.
2. It resizes the `paths` vector.  This can sometimes involve just increasing an integer, but at other times it involves moving every existing `Path` object and destroying the old ones.

In the first point, you have a leak.  `new` allocates objects on the free store, you are always responsible for ensuring they are cleaned up.  Copying the object off the free store into a vector does *not* clean up the object on the free store.

In the second point, `vector` actually holds actual objects, not references to them.  So when you resize the buffer (which `push_back` can do), you have to move the values of the objects around, then clean up the ones you are discarding.

That cleanup is the destructor you are doing.

You appear to be a C# or Java programmer.  In both of those languages, actual values of objects are really hard to create -- they want to hold onto garbage collected references to objects.  An array of objects is actually an array of **references to objects** in those languages.  In C++, a vector of objects is a vector **actually containing** the objects in question.

Your use of `new` is also a tip.  There is no need for `new` there, nor is there need for a pointer:

```
std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> RoverPlanner::get_paths(const char *filename) const
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    doc.load_file(filename);
    pugi::xml_node root = doc.document_element();

    std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> paths;
    for (auto&& path_node : root.children()) {
        std::vector<cuarl_path::Segment*> segments;
        for (auto segment_node : path_node.children())
        {
            //do stuff to populate the `segments` vector
        }

        cuarl_path::Path path = cuarl_path::Path(segments);
        paths.push_back(std::move(path)); //Path destructor called here
    }

    return paths;
}
```

you'll still get path destructors called on the line (in fact, you'll get an extra one), but your code won't leak.  Assuming your move constructor is correct (and in fact moves the state of the path properly), everything should work.

Now a more efficient version looks like:

```
std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> RoverPlanner::get_paths(const char *filename) const
{
    pugi::xml_document doc;
    doc.load_file(filename);
    pugi::xml_node root = doc.document_element();

    std::vector<cuarl_path::Path> paths;
    auto&& children = root.children();
    paths.reserve(children.size());
    for (auto path_node : children) {
        std::vector<cuarl_path::Segment*> segments;
        for (auto segment_node : path_node.children())
        {
            //do stuff to populate the `segments` vector
        }

        paths.emplace_back(std::move(segments));
    }

    return paths;
}
```

which gets rid of all of the temporary variables you are messing with, and moves resources when they are of no more use.

Assuming efficient move constructors, the big gains here are that we pre-researve the paths vector (saving lg(n) memory allocations) and we move the segments vector into the constructor of a path (if written right, that could avoid a needless copy of the buffer of segment pointers).

This version also has no destructors called on the line in question, but I don't consider that to be particularly important; the cost of a destructor of an empty path should be nearly free, and even plausible to optimize away.

I also possibly avoided a copy of the `path_node` object, which could be worth avoiding, depending on how it is written.